# Can a variable antenna matching component be adjusted using a servo with only two conductor cable?

Tags: antenna

I'm currently using one coax with a biastee station-side and a biastee top-side, to control rotation of a gear motor connected to an antenna matching component at the antenna feedpoint by simply reversing DC polarity station-side.
Is a servo operation possible instead using the limitation of one coax?
Advise freely and in detail please!  Many tnx to all!

Comment: Can information consisting of hundreds of control bits be transmitted across our solar system without any cable and with massive detailed information coming back in the opposite direction? If the answer is yes, then virtually anything is possible at a short distance using a coax cable. Of course, it requires a proper design.

Comment: Do you have power at the servo side? Or do you need to send both power and servo control over a single coax?

Answer (score 0):

You already have a bias Tee at each end of the cable, so you are free to transmit anything else with a low frequency along it.

The simplest, crudest design that springs to mind is to transmit DC power to the remote end to power the servo, and to send the control data to it by dropping the line. The remote end would have a diode+capacitor to keep the power consistent, and a simple detector to turn the line drops into clean data. The data could be as simple as a 'servo PWM' control signal, or could be serial comms from a control MCU to a remote MCU that handled the servo.

Answer (score 0):

Antenna tuning with a circuit which already is adjusted by a DC motor can well be servo controlled. It doesn't need more communication than you already have. You switch DC =ON could well be the command to the tuner to start its job.

The tuner must have what's needed to see the right adjustment. You transmit from the station room some r.f. at the wanted operating frequency at the same time and the servo in the tuner tries to find low enough VSWR position for the moving parts.

You may want to know how the tuner succeeded. It can be seen with another VSWR measurement tool at the station end. As well the tuner could be made to be able to send the result either with some ultra-simplified Morse code (=it adjusts its DC current consumption) or you could separate with more complex filtering a frequency band for communication. Now you have 2 bands, get 3 for this purpose.

There will be difficulties. Designing electronics which works when connected to a radio transmitter output is far from trivial. It's also difficult is to keep the noises of electronic circuits out of your microvolt level received radio signals. Except feeding no DC power to the tuner keeps it silent. Finally keeping electronics and motors functional up there in all environmental conditions is a challenge.  I suggest you to search for commercial devices which have all these already solved.